# Why my app gets closed when I perform a screen-lock test on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have Diawi Link for my app and I have download the app from there. Now, while using that if I do the screen lock and unlock after 6 minutes. It have to start with the same screen from where I locked the screen but it closes and I have to start the app from the beginning. Have you any idea regarding that why it is happening?

Comment: may be this will help you : http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-detect-when-an-app-is-coming-from-the-lockscreen-or-homescreen-on-ios-7/

Comment: iOS can terminate your app at any time. when it is suspended.  You should read up on and implement application state restoration; iOS provides facilities for your app to start up where it left off when it is relaunched.